# Java Hierarchical Enum Structure

Tags: java, enums

How can I make a hierarchical structure with Java enum? For example, I have following levels:

```
Level- [Level1, Level2]
Level1 - [Level1_1, Level1_2, Level1_3] 
Level2 - [Level2_1, Level2_2]
```

Can I create an enum 'Levels' like below, so I can access it  using `Level.Level1.Level1_1` or `Level.Level2.Level2_2` etc, 
Sub-levels should be accessed via its parent:

```
public enum Levels {
    Level1 {
        Level1_1,
        Level1_2,
        Level1_3
    },
    Level2 {
        Level2_1,
        Level2_2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is a little abstract, but any reason `Level1` and `Level2` can't be separate classes?

Comment: You can't do that with an enum.

Comment: what are you using the enum for? I think, you should use classes instead

Comment: Maybe something like my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636845/how-to-nest-an-enum-inside-the-value-of-an-enum/8960269#8960269).