# Best practice to hierarchically store constants

Tags: java, enums, interface

I'm working on webtests at the moment, using a WebDriver to simulate a browser. This WebDriver has to find HTML elements pretty often, many of them often being the same (i.e. a certain button, form field, etc.). The WebDriver needs an object of Selenium's `By` class, to use `findElement()`.

I figured it would be nice for readability and adaptability, if there was an **enum** or **interface** storing configured instances of `By`, which may be used to locate the element. In tests, repeatedly hard-coding `findElement(By.id("elementid"))` turns into `findElement(WebGui.Login.SUBMIT_BUTTON)`, where `WebGui.Login.SUBMIT_BUTTON` may return an instance of `By` searching for an ID, name, CSS class, etc. whatever is neccessary without concerning the test itself which just needs the element.

> **Question**
>   A hierarchical structure seems optimal to represent different sections of the website, however enums can't inherit anything. Which way is the most clean way and/or best practice?

**Nested Enum** As enums can't inherit `getBy()` and the constructor, so they must be defined in every nested enum, thus being more redundant code.

```
public enum WebGui {
    BUTTON1(By.id("button1")),
    SEND_BUTTON(By.name("sendButton"));

    private By searchCriteria;

    WebGui(By by) {
        searchCriteria = by;
    }

    public By getBy() {
        return searchCritera;
    }

    private enum SubPage {
        BUTTON2(By.id("button2")),
        SEND_BUTTON(By.linkText("Send"));

        private By searchCriteria;

        WebGui(By by) {
            searchCriteria = by;
        }

        public By getBy() {
            return searchCritera;
        }
    }
}
```

**Nested Interfaces/abstract classes** Using this seems less "clean", doesn't provide type safety (although not too relevant here) and is often refered to as bad practice, because storing a fixed set of available constants is an enums purpose.

**Edit** Nested Interfaces can't be private, therefore changed outer `interface` to `abstract class`

```
public abstract class WebGui {
    By BUTTON1 = By.id("button1");
    By SEND_BUTTON = By.name("sendButton");

    private interface SubPage {
        By BUTTON2 = By.id("button2");
        By SEND_BUTTON = By.linkText("Send");
    }
}
```

As nested Interfaces are much less code and its members don't need functions, using it seems to be the better choice, but how much of a bad practice is this, compared to nested enums containing redundant code.

Comment: In your first example - why is that inner enum *private*?

Comment: Why nest the interfaces/classes structurally? How about `class WebGui { ... public final SubPage1 subPage1 = new SubPage1(); }`?

Comment: @GhostCat I tried to avoid the inner enums to be accessible from outside, without using WebGui.Login, as they only make sense in WebGui-context. However, this turned out to not work as intended...

Comment: @JimmyB This still requires the class to be visible (public), in which case I can also but the class itself into WebGui (static inner class). I tried to implement a solution which does not expose the inner enum/class to all classes, except they use WebGui.InnerClass. Seems like this is not possible the way I intended it :/

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you, but to clarify my idea: WebGui becomes a singleton. Then you access all data via `webGuiSingleton.subPage1.xyz`. Unless someone manually creates an instance of e.g. `SubPage1` and uses it, the 'API' seems to be pretty fool-proof.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JimmyB. My idea of an optimal solution was a hierarchie whose nested classes/enums are hidden from the outside, only accessible using `OuterClass.InnerClass.ELEMENT` (`InnerClass.ELEMENT` is supposed to be impossible), but I played around a little more and it turns out, it does not work the way I intended. Probably gonna use the Interface/Class approach as it's more readable and type safety is not really required (type of the members themselves is important). If I come across a more elegant solution, I'll edit my posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the enum implement an interface like my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636845/how-to-nest-an-enum-inside-the-value-of-an-enum/8960269#8960269).